# Ruby on rails checkbox (when clicked to div, enable checkbox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want checkbox to be clicked when **div.tel_show** is clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("div.tel_show").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});
</script>
```

I think I need to change **var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");**
what should I write instead of input[type='checkbox']

```
  <div class="row">
    <div id="media-contents" class="col-lg-12">
      <% if @media_contents.empty? %>
        <h2 id="no-media">Dosya Bulunamadı</h2>
      <% else %>
        <% @media_contents.each do |media| %>
          <div class="col-lg-4 tel_show">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag media.file_name.url %>
              <div class="caption">
                <p>
                  <%= check_box_tag "media_contents[]", media.id %>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier if you actually post your rendered DOM instead of the Ruby template, since that is what your Javascript code is actually working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div").live("click",function(event) 
 {

var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
       checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
       checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkbox a `class` or an `id`, then use e.g. `$('#checkbox_id')` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Input type selectors should not have '' around the type, e.g. should be `"input[type=checkbox]"` instead of `"input[type='checkbox']"`.